# May I instantiate a templated object A<B> containing a deque of objects of type A<B>?

Tags: c++, llvm

I would like to understand if the following code is correct in general, or not:

```
#include <deque>

template<class T>
struct Node {
    std::deque<Node<T> > branches;
    T data;

    Node(const T& _data) : data(_data) {
    }

};

void dummy() {
    Node<float> test(5.0f);
}
```

This code was compiled with several toolchains without ever generating errors (See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1de835a057536354) for example).
The problem is that now I get an instantiation error (maybe related to the fact that I am using llvm libc++, not sure about the version).

```
<...>llvm-libc++/include/deque:912:55: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'std::__1::__deque_base<Node<float>, std::__    1::allocator<Node<float> > >::value_type {aka Node<float>}'
     static const difference_type __block_size = sizeof(value_type) < 256 ? 4096 / sizeof(value_type) : 16;
```

In case this code is correct, I am not interested to investigate the origin of the bug (compiler or std library implementation) or to have a workaround: again, I mainly would like to understand if the code above is formally correct.

Comment: Though the C++ template system is, via template metaprogramming, in  some senses more powerful than C# generic types, here we have an example of how something that can be expressed in a generic type system cannot be expressed in a templating system. If this subject interests you, you might want to look at my implementation of a generic finger tree deque in C# that uses a recursively defined generic type. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/12/immutability-in-c-part-eleven-a-working-double-ended-queue/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The code is ill-formed. At this point:

```
template<class T>
struct Node {
    std::deque<Node<T> > branches; // <==
```

`Node<T>` is still an incomplete type. There are currently built-in exceptions for incomplete types for three of the containers:

- "An incomplete type `T` may be used when instantiating `forward_list` if the allocator satisfies the allocator
  completeness requirements 17.6.3.5.1. `T` shall be complete before any member of the resulting specialization
  of `forward_list` is referenced." [[forwardlist.overview]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/forwardlist.overview#4)
- "An incomplete type `T` may be used when instantiating `list` if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness
  requirements 17.6.3.5.1. `T` shall be complete before any member of the resulting specialization of `list` is
  referenced." [[list.overview]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/list.overview#3)
- "An incomplete type `T` may be used when instantiating `vector` if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness
  requirements 17.6.3.5.1. `T` shall be complete before any member of the resulting specialization of
  `vector` is referenced." [[vector.overview]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.overview#3)

There is no such wording for `deque`, which currently requires a complete type. Seems inconsistent to me to allow incomplete types for `vector` but not `deque`, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug in your compiler nor the standard library. The program is ill formed. You may not instantiate `std::deque` with an incomplete value type.